# ¿Porque no se dispara el event listener en este codigo?

Tags: javascript, html

estoy tratando que se agregue otro <option con texto en en el primer <select pero el código ni siquiera se dispara cuando se le hace click al <option que tiene el manejador de eventos, incluso disparando la funcion addAnaquel directamente en consola el <option programado no se crea

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit arcu blandit luctus consequat donec, ante dignissim nascetur litora lectus nulla feugiat interdum ultricies orci mi, elementum nam fringilla aliquam cum urna metus neque inceptos ad est. Nullam ante cursus himenaeos bibendum neque purus justo ut, felis proin est primis nisl non pulvinar libero, condimentum metus cubilia odio vulputate turpis risus. Porta elementum cursus inceptos nostra imperdiet montes pharetra odio varius class maecenas, laoreet dignissim praesent augue nisi gravida sapien magnis parturient natoque, luctus lacus senectus justo nam at netus tempus lectus bibendum.

```
  <body>
    <form class="databox" action="index.html" method="post">
      <label for="">Numero de pieza: </label><input type="number" name="" class="pieza" id="pie" value="">
        <label for="">Descripcion: </label><input type="text" class="descripcion" name="" value="">
      <label for="">Implemento/Tractor: </label><input type="text" class="type" name="" value="">
      <label for="">Precio: </label><input type="text" name="" value="" class="price">
      <label for="">Cantidad: </label><input type="text" name="" value="" class="cantidad">
      <label for="">Anaquel: </label>
      <select class="select" name="anaquel">
        <option value="">1</option>
        <option id="anamas" value="">+</option>

      </select>
      <label for="">Repisa: </label><select class="seleccion" name="">
        <option value="">1</option>
        <option id="+2" value="">+</option>
      </select>
      <label for="">Poveedor: </label><input type="text" name="" value="">
      <label for="">foto: </label><input type="file" name="" value="">
      <button type="button" name="button" onclick="escribir()">Capturar</button>
    </form>
    <div id="repisa"></div>

    <script>
    
       function escribir() {
             // var pieza = document.getElementsByClassName("pieza").value;
             var pieza =  document.querySelector(".pieza").value;
           console.log(pieza)          
          }
    
     let newoption = document.createElement("option") 
     var id = document.querySelector(".id")
     var masanaquel = document.getElementById("anamas")
     var select = document.getElementsByClassName("select")[0]
     

         
         
     function addAnaquel() {
     select.appendChild(newoption);
     console.log(select)
     debugger
     }

  
     masanaquel.addEventListener("click", addAnaquel)
     
     
         </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que debes de poner el ID en el select y no en el option.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="databox" action="index.html" method="post">
          <label for="">Numero de pieza: </label><input type="number" name="" class="pieza" id="pie" value="">
            <label for="">Descripcion: </label><input type="text" class="descripcion" name="" value="">
          <label for="">Implemento/Tractor: </label><input type="text" class="type" name="" value="">
          <label for="">Precio: </label><input type="text" name="" value="" class="price">
          <label for="">Cantidad: </label><input type="text" name="" value="" class="cantidad">
          <label for="">Anaquel: </label>
          <select class="select" name="anaquel" id="anamas">
            <option value="">1</option>
            <option value="">+</option>
    
          </select>
          <label for="">Repisa: </label><select class="seleccion" name="">
            <option value="">1</option>
            <option id="+2" value="">+</option>
          </select>
          <label for="">Poveedor: </label><input type="text" name="" value="">
          <label for="">foto: </label><input type="file" name="" value="">
          <button type="button" name="button" onclick="escribir()">Capturar</button>
        </form>
        <div id="repisa"></div>
    
        <script>
        
           function escribir() {
                 // var pieza = document.getElementsByClassName("pieza").value;
                 var pieza =  document.querySelector(".pieza").value;
               console.log(pieza)          
              }
        
         let newoption = document.createElement("option") 
         var id = document.querySelector(".id")
         var masanaquel = document.getElementById("anamas")
         var select = document.getElementsByClassName("select")[0]
         
    
             
             
         function addAnaquel() {
             console.log("Cambiado");
         select.appendChild(newoption);
         console.log(select)
         }
    
      
         masanaquel.addEventListener("input", addAnaquel)
         
         
             </script>
      </body>
    </html>
</html>
```